# Compile libraries for ARM toolchain(buildroot)

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling, toolchain, buildroot

I am using buildroot's toolchain to cross compile applications for ARM. However some application requires libraries that are not compiled for that tool chain. I have those libraries on my host tool chain like -ljack, lfftw etc.

I need to know that if I get tarball of the required packages then how can I configure them so that the libraries are compiled by arm-gcc and the headers/libraries copied to /usr and /include of the buildroot ?

In this way I should be able to access these libraries via buildroot's toolchain.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

Well, you need to integrate them into Buildroot.

Take fftw for example, in that particular case, fftw is already available in Buildroot, and you just have to enable it in your build. Go to `Target packages`->`Libraries`->`Other` and enable `fftw`.

If you don't know where to find a package, run `make menuconfig` and type `Ctrl-/` to get a search box. There you could type e.g. fftw and learn where in the menu system it is located and what dependencies it has.

If fftw (or some other library you need) hadn't been / isn't available in Buildroot, you need to add it yourself. See e.g. [adding packages to Buildroot](http://www.buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#adding-packages).

Comment: Thanks, yes the packages can be added to buildroot and then images can be built but what if one already has the distribution and he wants to manually compile the libraries and put them into the directories ? 

I know thats not the the proper way but for some applications with little dependencies, one should be able to manually link them ?

It should also be possible ?

Comment: Sure, I guess that you could manually install everything in the sysroot... And/or point gcc to where you're have the headers and libraries... Though I'd recommend against that. Maybe I'm biased as I'm working with embedded systems, but I always want to build system (in this case Buildroot) to build everything, as that's the only way to get reliable and reproducible builds.